# An American equivalent for "to do the dirty on someone"?

Tags: american-english, expressions, british-english, australian-english

*To do the dirty on someone* means, in Australian and British English,

> to behave unfairly or very badly towards someone, often without them knowing. *And then he did the dirty on her and went and had an affair with her best friend.*
>   — [The free dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+the+dirty+on)

which I think is a pretty cool and useful idiom. However, it seems it isn't used in American English, so what would be the AmE version?

IOW, how would you rephrase the sentence above so that it sounds idiomatic in AmE?:

*And then he _____ (her) and went and had an affair with her best friend.*

Comment: If it's true that idiom isn't yet recognised in US American English, why not just introduce it? Who might misunderstand?

Answer (score 2):

The most "American" version I can think of is [to do someone wrong](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/do-someone-wrong).  You would normally phrase it as *he did her wrong* although in informal, idiomatic speech you sometimes see it as ["**done** someone wrong"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBU6H5wNWlo).

Comment: In the Southern US, doing me/him/her dirty is used by some.

Answer (score 1):

There are several terms for what you are looking for

> betray
>   double-cross
>   deceive
>   talk behind *someone's* back *(both figuratively and literally)*

In AmE

> [to do the dirty](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=do%20the%20dirty)

has a completely different meaning.

Comment: Had  no idea the British English meaning *didn't* mean what the UD link says!

Answer (score 0):

Double-crossed? Other than that, we do use "did you dirty" as an idiom sometimes but it's not very common.

Answer (score -1):

Another possible American expression, though in a narrower context, is:

**She threw him under the bus.**

It means to maneuver in a competitive business environment in such a way that another person is positioned to receive responsibility and blame for a situation. The scapegoat is usually blindsided.