doing the dirty
On television I heard an American woman say about her pregnant teenage daughter: "I thought she was a neat girl, not doing the dirty."
I assume that "doing the dirty" is a rather vulgar phrase meaning "having sex". The adult mother may well engage in sexual activity herself too, but she would presumably choose different words to express this.

You could ask the same about 'neat' which does not mean "does not have sex". The quoted sentence should be taken in the context of the TV show it was heard on.

Yes "doing the dirty" means "having sex"..... What is your question?

Another common phrase in the UK for having sex is "do the nasty"

It is a truncated form of "doing the dirty deed" which is, as you surmised, a colloquial derogatory periphrasis for  "fornicating".  I suppose one could debate whether doing the dirty  is a euphemistic  version of the dysphemism.
P.S. Compare this  thread  from a student chat forum from the year 2021:

Title : My GF is talking to her male coworker, should I be worried?
Response from Anonymous#4 : She's doing the dirty, PM me and we can chat about it x

And this from Pulp International (Oct 2011)

Also on the cover of Exposed, like clockwork, appears Ava Gardner. Readers are told she’s doing the dirty with Italian actor Walter Chiari. This would have been after splitting with Frank Sinatra but before the official divorce.


I'm not sure if you're being humourous, but periphrasis and dysphenism are of doubtful benefit as words to explain a concept on a learners website. The overemployment of such esoteric linguistic jargon in the context of a educational facility for autodidacts is surely best circumvented by brevity. Let us not fall into the sin of sesquipedalian lexis.

'Doing a dirty' means something else, I think.

+1 for making the point I wanted to, that it's to some degree a euphemism, albeit one that's "low" in tone. But I agree it would be better to explain that in more learner-friendly language.

@fred2   I was addressing the OP's "I assume [it's] a rather vulgar phrase".  To understand the phrase in a more nuanced manner  one needs to understand two concepts: euphemism and dysphemism. These words will help anyone, learners included, find their way to discussions of the subject from a sociolinguistic angle, if they're interested.

And the fact that they may be learning to express themselves in English doesn't mean they're people incapable of sophisticated or nuanced thought.

"Doing the dirty (on)" has no specific reference to sexual (mis)behaviour.
As the Cambridge dictionary puts it: It's to behave unfairly towards someone, usually without their knowledge.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do-the-dirty-on

"Doing the dirty on" is an idiom, but "doing the dirty" is slang with a sexual connotation, so I don't think your answer is correct. Cambridge won't include relatively recent and vulgar slang uses, but there's ample evidence online for its use in this way.

Of interest: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94050/an-american-equivalent-for-to-do-the-dirty-on-someone

I can see how this is confusing as there are several similar idioms/euphemisms all with different meanings. Actually, I think the person you quote may have mixed up two sayings. Even native English speakers are not above getting language wrong, especially when it comes to idioms.
"Doing the dirty on [someone]" means to double-cross them. It doesn't have to involve sex. It could refer to cheating on a partner with a sexual act, but even in that context, the phrase doesn't directly refer to the sexual act; it refers to the betrayal.
"A dirty deed" can refer to any bad, intentional act. Again, it isn't inherently sexual. But using the definite article and saying "the dirty deed" implies sex. However, your quote doesn't use the word 'deed'.
I think the person you are quoting may have meant to say "doing the nasty", which unequivocally means engaging in sexual intercourse, and they have just confused it with one of the above sayings.
